# How can I obtain multiple random samples at once from a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 100 rows. I want to obtain 50 random samples of 10 rows each without replacement and put each of them in a data frame. Please how can I do this without having to repeat myself 50 times?

I have tried to use Sample_n from dplyr package with the code below, but it can only handle one random sample at a time. I am new to R and your answer is going to broaden my knowledge.

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:100,
                   x2 = "x",
                   x3 = "y")
library(dplyr)
sample_n(data, 10, Replace = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a data frame with 100 rows
data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:100, x2 = "x", x3 = "y")

# set the number of samples and the sample size
num_samples <- 50
sample_size <- 10

# create an empty list to store the samples
samples_list <- list()

# loop through the number of samples
for (i in 1:num_samples) {
  # sample 10 rows without replacement and store in the list
  samples_list[[i]] <- data[sample(nrow(data), sample_size, replace = FALSE), ]
}

# view the first sample
head(samples_list[[1]])
```

Comment: This is helpful. Solved it @Reily

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the same operation multiple times, you can use `replicate()`. Note that by default it tries to simplify the results but if you just want a list of samples, then you want to turn that off

```
samples <- replicate(50, sample_n(data, 10, replace = F), simplify = FALSE)
```

Then you can apply whatever function you want over the list of samples.

Comment: This answer helped me to handle it  @MrFlick